# What language constructs or API is deprecated by ECMA 2015 / ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

ES5 introduce `"use strict"` and normatively define what language constructions and API usage are deprecated / obsolete.

Links to specs is referenced in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Language_Resources

I tried to read ES6 and make searches for *deprecated* / *obsolete* keywords but didn't find anything related.

I compared Annex C of ES6 and ES5 (*The Strict Mode of ECMAScript* section) and they are mostly identical.

What language constructs or API is deprecated by ECMA 2015 / ES6?

Comment: I know that AppCache is deprecated, although it’s not part of ECMAScript…

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of deprecated features on MDN pages : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features

On each function page, you can also see a deprecation notice.
And a thumb-down or trashbin icon next to their names.

Comment: The question is what are the ES6 deprecations, if any.

Comment: While I agree this is not a ES5/ES6 comparison page. It still lists all applicable deprecations. ES5 strict mode was introduce to prepare ES6. In my knowledge, nothing really changed appart from the "duplicate property names" relaxed in ES6